# Postgresql - special character values

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to insert a number which has special character, example 8_3 into table. But the number gets stored as 83 in the database as opposed to 8_3. I'm using Psycopg for inserting data.

```
cursor.execute('''Insert into frame_data(iden)values(%s);''',(int(key))
```

Comment: If the presence of `_` is important, then it is not a number but a **string** and should be stored as such.

Comment: Thanks. Changed the int to str and it works.